# Unhandled exception rendering component: '<' is an invalid start of a value

Tags: api, entity-framework, error-handling, blazor, blazor-webassembly

just started with Blazor created my first app its a CRUD app with api. But i get this huge error and i can't figure out what is wrong and what it actual means? think something with the api links? I've tried the [Unhandled exception rendering component: '<' is an invalid start of a value for Blazor WASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288643/unhandled-exception-rendering-component-is-an-invalid-start-of-a-value-for) solutions but none of these seems to work for me. I'm using the blazor webassembly in visualstudio 17.2.0 with entityframework.

When i start my project i get this message at the bottom of my page :

> An unhandled error has occurred. Reload
>
> blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: '<' is an invalid start of a value.
> Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.  --->
> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '<' is an invalid start of a
> value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader&
> json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes) at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TreviData.Shared.Models.Ewons, TreviData.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TreviData.Shared.Models.Ewons, TreviData.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[List`1](JsonConverter
> jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options,
> ReadStack& state)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[List`1](JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer,
> JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, JsonConverter
> converterBase)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ContinueDeserialize[List`1](ReadBufferState& bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack, JsonConverter converter, JsonSerializerOptions options)    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.<ReadAllAsync>d__65`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TreviData.Shared.Models.Ewons, TreviData.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()    at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.<ReadFromJsonAsyncCore>d__4`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TreviData.Shared.Models.Ewons, TreviData.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()    at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__13`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TreviData.Shared.Models.Ewons,
> TreviData.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()    at
> TreviData.Client.Pages.EwonDetails.GetUser() in
> C:\Users\toonw\source\repos\TreviData\TreviData\Client\Pages\EwonDetails.razor:line
> 73    at TreviData.Client.Pages.EwonDetails.OnInitializedAsync() in
> C:\Users\toonw\source\repos\TreviData\TreviData\Client\Pages\EwonDetails.razor:line
> 69    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
> taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
> window.Module.s.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
> Fe._internal.dotNetCriticalError @ blazor.webassembly.js:1 St @
> blazor.webassembly.js:1
> _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @ dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1 $func219 @ 00971e46:0x1a490 $func167 @ 00971e46:0xce5e $func166 @ 00971e46:0xbd71
> $func2812 @ 00971e46:0xabf01 $func1616 @ 00971e46:0x6fcc2 $func1620 @
> 00971e46:0x7032f $mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00971e46:0x969d
> Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1
> managed_BINDINGS_SetTaskSourceResult @
> managed_BINDINGS_SetTaskSourceResult:17 (anonymous) @
> dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1 Promise.then (async)
> _wrap_js_thenable_as_task @ dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1
> _js_to_mono_obj @ dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1
> _mono_wasm_invoke_js_with_args @ dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1 $func219 @ 00971e46:0x1a449 $func167 @ 00971e46:0xce5e $func166 @
> 00971e46:0xbd71 $func2812 @ 00971e46:0xabf01 $func1616 @
> 00971e46:0x6fcc2 $func1620 @ 00971e46:0x7032f $mono_wasm_invoke_method
> @ 00971e46:0x969d Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @
> dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1 managed_BINDINGS_SetTaskSourceResult @
> managed_BINDINGS_SetTaskSourceResult:17 (anonymous) @
> dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1 Promise.then (async)
> _wrap_js_thenable_as_task @ dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1
> _js_to_mono_obj @ dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1
> _mono_wasm_invoke_js_with_args @ dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1 $func219 @ 00971e46:0x1a449 $func167 @ 00971e46:0xce5e $func166 @
> 00971e46:0xbd71 $func2812 @ 00971e46:0xabf01 $func1616 @
> 00971e46:0x6fcc2 $func1614 @ 00971e46:0x6fc34 $func967 @
> 00971e46:0x50685 $func219 @ 00971e46:0x1a449 $func167 @
> 00971e46:0xce5e $func166 @ 00971e46:0xbd71 $func2812 @
> 00971e46:0xabf01 $func1616 @ 00971e46:0x6fcc2 $func1620 @
> 00971e46:0x7032f $mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00971e46:0x969d
> Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.6.0.5.wc6fu8n2ms.js:1
> managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_BeginInvokeDotNet
> @
> managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_BeginInvokeDotNet:19 beginInvokeDotNetFromJS @ blazor.webassembly.js:1 b @
> blazor.webassembly.js:1 e.invokeMethodAsync @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
> (anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1 ve @ blazor.webassembly.js:1 we
> @ blazor.webassembly.js:1 (anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
> (anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1 onGlobalEvent @
> blazor.webassembly.js:1

Here is my code.

**AddEwon.Razor**

```
    @page "/ewon/add/"
    @page "/ewon/edit/{Id:int}"
    @using TreviData.Shared.Models
    @inject HttpClient Http
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
    <h1>@Title Ewon</h1>
    <hr />
    <EditForm Model="@ewon" OnValidSubmit="SaveEwon">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Name" class="form-label">EwonName</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="ewon.EwonName" />
            </div>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ewon.EwonName)" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Address" class="form-label">ApiKey</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="ewon.ApiKey" />
            </div>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ewon.ApiKey)" />
        </div>
    
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-light" @onclick="Cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
    @code {
        [Parameter]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        protected string Title = "Add";
        protected Ewons ewon = new();
        protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
            if (Id != 0)
            {
                Title = "Edit";
                ewon = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Ewons>("api/ewon/" + Id);
            }
        }
        protected async Task SaveEwon()
        {
            if (ewon.Id != 0)
            {
                await Http.PutAsJsonAsync("api/ewon", ewon);
            }
            else
            {
                await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ewon", ewon);
            }
            Cancel();
        }
        public void Cancel()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/fetchewondetails");
        }
    }
```

**FetchData.Razor**

```
  @page "/ewondetails"
@using TreviData.Shared.Models
@inject HttpClient Http
<h1>Ewon Data</h1>
<p>Ewons api-keys.</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href='/ewon/add' class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
            <i class="fas fa-ewon-plus"></i>
            Add Ewon
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Ewon by name"
               @bind="SearchString" @bind:event="oninput" @onkeyup="FilterUser" />
        @if (SearchString.Length > 0)
        {
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="ResetSearch">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<br />
@if (ewonList == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-striped align-middle table-bordered">
        <thead class="table-success">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Ewon Name</th>
                <th>Api key</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var e in ewonList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@e.Id</td>
                    <td>@e.EwonName</td>
                    <td>@e.ApiKey</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href='/ewon/edit/@e.Id' class="btn btn-outline-dark" role="button">
                            Edit
                        </a>
                        <a href='/ewon/delete/@e.Id' class="btn btn-outline-danger" role="button">
                            Delete
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
}
@code {
    protected List<Ewons> ewonList = new();
    protected List<Ewons> searchEwonData = new();
    protected Ewons ewon = new();
    protected string SearchString { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetUser();
    }
    protected async Task GetUser()
    {
        ewonList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Ewons>>("api/ewon");
        searchEwonData = ewonList;
    }
    protected void FilterUser()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
        {
            ewonList = searchEwonData
                .Where(x => x.EwonName.IndexOf(SearchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
                .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            ewonList = searchEwonData;
        }
    }
    protected void DeleteConfirm(int Id)
    {
        ewon = ewonList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
    }
    public void ResetSearch()
    {
        SearchString = string.Empty;
        ewonList = searchEwonData;
    }
```

}

**EwonController**

```
using TreviData.Server.InterFaces;
using TreviData.Shared.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace TreviData.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IEwons _IEwons;
        public UserController(IEwons iEwons)
        {
            _IEwons = iEwons;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<Ewons>> Get()
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(_IEwons.GetEwonDetails());
        }
        [HttpGet("{Id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            Ewons ewon = _IEwons.GetEwonData(id);
            if (ewon != null)
            {
                return Ok(ewon);
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post(Ewons ewon)
        {
            _IEwons.AddEwon(ewon);
        }
        [HttpPut]
        public void Put(Ewons ewons)
        {
            _IEwons.UpdateEwonDetails(ewons);
        }
        [HttpDelete("{Id}")]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            _IEwons.DeleteEwon(id);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the error is in the `GetFromJsonAsync` call returning nothing - there's a lot of code to plough through!

You are calling `api/ewon/`, but your controller is defined as:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
/....
```

which has the url "api/user".

So sort out your controller name or your calls.

You should always test your APIs with Postman!

Comment: Where did you find api/user?

Comment: @user19108801 : That's an Asp.net convention.  `[Route("api/[controller]")]` + `UserController` = `api/user`

Comment: As Henk says, in the `Ewon` code block in your question.  Have you tested with Postman?  That's where you need to start.

Comment: For sure your controller is retuning error in the form of html which always starts with < and you are not able to deserialize it as List<Ewons> on client side. Go with @MrCakaShaunCurtis and test your end-point first

Answer (score 0):

I got this error but mine I had my controller name correct and I fixed it after I found out that "GetFromJsonAsync" of the HttpClient is case sensitive.

So if your controller is not routed explicitly, you might want to make it be exactly like the Controller name so the case will match what you pass as a string.

So this line will be
**ewonList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List>("api/Ewon");**

Some other way might be configuring the Json options so serialization/Deserialization can be case insensitive.

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
});
```

Comment: `SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` is `false` by default, I guess you meant setting it to `true` to disable case-sensitivity of property names during JSON deserialization. But then, what do JSON properties have to do with routes and their case-sensitivity?